# How do I make my 2D character's legs snap to non flat terrain?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, game-physics, game-development

I am creating a 2D platformer type game, and it has non flat terrain. How do I make it so that my character's legs always smoothly transition from a flat surface to a slope surface?

For reference you can check out [Alto's Adventure] (http://altosadventure.com/) (mobile). In that, the skateboard snaps to the curvy terrain.

Feel free to ask for more details.

Answer (score 0):

To make such a possibility, you have to send a `ray` to the ground and then set the direction of up transform according to the [Normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)) vector point of impact. The following code solves the basic problem.

```cs
public LayerMask groundLayer;
public float maxRayLength = 3;
public float offset = .5f; // set it to half of your character height

public void Update()
{
    var ground = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.up, maxRayLength, groundLayer.value);

    if (ground)
    {
        transform.up = ground.normal;

        transform.position = new Vector3(ground.point.x, ground.point.y) + transform.up*offset;
    }
}
```

In addition to the script, you must specify a suitable 2D collider as well as its layer. For layers, make sure that both the script inspector and the layer are set to the hypothetical ground layer.

[image]

[image]

---

### Example Result:

[image]